# Editing a Django package inside a docker container

Tags: django, docker, containers

In my Django docker file, I'm using the pip install -r requirements.txt file. Through this, I'm downloading a certain package but that package needs to be edited once installed. On my local computer, I can just go to the site-packages and edit it but I need to know where can I find it inside a container? Or is it even possible? I'm fairly new to docker so please help me out.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve, but this is definitely doable.

Method 1: Copy the modified package and import it directly.

For eg: if `numpy` is the library you need to modify, copy the entire `numpy` directory to your project and make the changes. Import this instead of the official library.

Make sure to copy this folder to your container too.

Remove `numpy` from your requirements file, this is to prevent docker from reinstalling the original `numpy`.

This way you can distribute your project easily.

Method 2(**NOT RECOMMENDED**): Modify it directly inside the container.

Use docker exec to run `nano` if installed.
Another easy way to do this would be using the docker extension in VSCode or your preferred IDE.

The disadvantage is you can't distribute this easily.

If this is an open source library, you can also suggest this change. Though it would be a slow process to approve.